# Codename One - Unwanted padding/spacing in ScaleImageLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, codenameone

New to Codename One, moving over from Android "native" java development.

I'm trying to create a SideMenu design that loosely resembles the Material side menu, as seen in just about every Google app (e.g. Play Store). Starting with a header image, I can't seem to get rid of some padding on the top and bottom:

[image: simulator screenshot]

The white bars on the top and bottom are unwanted. Current code:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    home = new Home();

    // SideMenu header BG image
    Image headerImage = theme.getImage("bg_navdrawer_header.png");
    ScaleImageLabel sideMenuHeaderBg = new ScaleImageLabel(headerImage);
    sideMenuHeaderBg.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);

    // SideMenu header app title
    Label sideMenuHeaderLabel = new Label("Title");
    sideMenuHeaderLabel.setUIID("SideMenuHeaderTitle");

    Container sideMenuHeader = new Container();
    sideMenuHeader.add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(sideMenuHeaderBg, FlowLayout.encloseBottom(sideMenuHeaderLabel)));
    home.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(sideMenuHeader);

    home.show();
}
```

The white bars disappear if I use BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL, but then it doesn't keep aspect ratio - it stretches to fill those two white spaces. (EDIT: It *does* keep aspect ratio, but it clips the longer dimension). I've tried setting the UIID to "Container" to... everything, makes no difference.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:**

For some reason, calling setWidth on the ScaledImageView immediately after setting the background type solved it. Doesn't matter what the width is, any number at all and the "letterboxing" is gone and the height is as it should be.

```
ScaleImageLabel sideMenuHeaderBg = new ScaleImageLabel(headerImage);
sideMenuHeaderBg.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
sideMenuHeaderBg.setWidth(0);
```

Going to leave this open in case somebody has a better solution or can at least explain why this is the case, or exactly what is happening since my solution is more of a hack than an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

`BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL` should keep aspect ratio.  It resizes the image to "fill" the space's shorter dimension.  The longer dimension is clipped.

`BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED` will stretch to fill the space, but won't keep aspect ratio.

`BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT` will also keep aspect ratio.  It resizes the image to "fill" the space's longer dimension.  The shorter dimension is "letterboxed", as you see in your screenshot.

Comment: So FILL does keep aspect ratio, just clips the longer dimension. But I don't want any clipping at all. I want it to fill the space's longer dimension *without* letterboxing. Where is this letterbox coming from? I just want it to fit snugly against the top and not have the white space at the bottom.

Comment: Also style `StatusBarSideMenu` to have 0 padding/margin